# Determining the function g for Stokes' theorem

Tags: functions, stokes-theorem

I'm going through the examples provided in my textbook (Advanced Engineering Mathematics, 5th Edition) on Stokes theorem.

In the following example, I don't understand how $g(x, y, z) = z + x^2 -1$ was determined.

[image]

The function starts as $z = 1 - x^2$, which to my understanding would be a function of 2 parameters x, y, such that $f(x, y) = 1 - x$. I'm aware this can be rearranged to $0 = z + x^2 - 1$, but I don't understand the reason as to how $0$ can be replaced with $g(x, y, z)$. Would somebody please care to explain?

Comment: Would like an explanation on this too!

Comment: The equation $z + x^2 - 1 = 0$ defines the surface. What they are saying is that if you take the function $g(x,y,z) : = z+ x^2 -1$, then the 0-level is the surface.  With that said, I'm more worried about them calling this shape a cylinder.

Comment: @LeonSot Hah yeah, it's a parabola extruded along the y axis. Can you please explain the level surface? I never really understood it =/

Comment: So a point (x,y,z) is on the surface if it satisfies the equation $ z + x^2 -1 =0 $ when you sub in the values. However, this is the same as if I subbed these values into $g(x,y,z)$ and it outputted $0$. Hence, these two things define the same surface.

Comment: But $g(x, y, z)$ only defines the same surface for particular values of $x, y, z$ which happen to make it equal to 0. So they're not always equivalent. Why did we make that "jump"?